# Adding a nuget that has core references to a an older core project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-standard

I have am creating a .NET standard package that has version 2.1.1 of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http nuget package in it.

I need to add this nuget to all of our core projects and I add it to a test core project of the same version and it works great, but when I try to add it to a project with version 2.0.6 of Microsoft.AspNetCore.All and I get a version conflict

> Assembly 'Nuget.Project' with identity 'Nuget.Project,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx' which has a higher version than
>   referenced assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions' with
>   identity 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.0.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx'

I changed the tokens to x's and replaced the name of the project for privacy reasons.

My Nuget is accessing HttpContext so I need the Core in it. I don't know how to make the nuget package okay to put on older versions.

Comment: 2.0.6 is obsolete. You must upgrade that project from .NET Core 2.0 to 2.1, and that's exactly why the conflicts happened.

Comment: Lex, thank you for the comment. Is there any way I can up the compatibility so that it works on all ASP Core 2.X projects? This is a nuget that will go on all of our applications and it isn't that helpful if we have to upgrade all of our projects when we create a new project, then have to upgrade this nuget to the latest core, then have to upgrade all the other projects to the latest core.

Comment: It is pointless to talk about "ASP.NET Core 2.X" here, because you can only use 2.1 today (2.0 is obsolete and 2.2 is just in preview).

Comment: Also, I wouldn't go as far as to say 2.0.6 is obsolete, its only half a year old and it still supported by Microsoft. If I had an ASP Core 1.0 app then I would see that more so, but its only .1 version behind

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/06/20/net-core-2-0-will-reach-end-of-life-on-september-1-2018/ Only if you never read the lifecycle announcement and policies.

Comment: Well played! Thank you for the reference, I'll include that in my documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a very specific issue that no one else got, but posting my fix in case someone else got the issue.

In my nuspec package I didn't put the dependencies and their versions. I didn't need to for my test project that has the same version of Core. I went ahead and listed all dependencies and and their versions and it worked. I guess it makes a difference when installing on websites with different versions of the respective software.

If that doesn't work I also uninstalled and reinstalled the dependencies on the Nuget, if that helps anyone.

Although, upvotes to Lex Li for suggesting we not use a deprecated version of Core. I will put that in my report we should upgrade.